# Ruby on Rails Connecting With Sql Express 2005

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a VPS having Debian Wheezy. I have my Ruby on Rails application deployed here. The database resides on its parallel Windows box having Sql Server 2005 Express Edition. I have ruby **ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]**, rails **Rails 4.1.5**, tiny_tds **tiny_tds (0.6.2)** and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter **activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0)**
the connecting string details are under the following

```
gwdb:  
  dataserver: '23.254.130.27\SQLEXPRESS' # event commented this out
  host: 23.254.130.27 # tried like '23.254.130.27\SQLEXPRESS' didn't work
  username: "RMDx"
  password: "N7DF5I9CW0"
  database: "Gateway"
  adapter: "sqlserver"
```

but getting the following exception

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection': ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:180:in `subclass_from_attributes?'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:23:in `new'
        from /home/gatewayv2-chile/app/controllers/sa.gw.p.controller.rb:80:in `initialize'
        from /home/gatewayv2-chile/app/controllers/sa.gw.p.controller.rb:324:in `new'
        from /home/gatewayv2-chile/app/controllers/sa.gw.p.controller.rb:324:in `<main>'
```

Plz guide me to connect with Sql Server Express edition. 
**Note** the application works fine with Sql Sever 2005, 2008 enterprise editions

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your read [Developing with MS SQL on your Mac](http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/202-developing-with-ms-sql-on-your-mac) blog post from [Sebastian Porto](https://twitter.com/sebasporto), where he nicely explains few tricks and tips - it involves Mac but it should get you up to speed.

Comment: followed the article but at then end of day I was standing right where I started. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in [TinyTds Readme](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#tinytdsclient-usage), `:host` must be used only if `:dataserver` is blank.